# Moodle Function API doc over REST

Tags: android, web-services, rest, moodle

I am trying to develop a Moodle Android app. I am using MoodleREST source code for my reference.Is there any other documentation on Moodle site which documents moodle core webservice functions with their required params.

I have found list of functions here http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services_Roadmap but could not get proper documentation on how to call these functions with required params from mobile client using REST.

I am new to moodle and still learning it, so my question can be a little naive so please bear with it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be helpful http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

And if you have some administrator access to Moodle, go to

yourmoodle/admin/webservice/documentation.php , or

*Administration > Plugins > Web services > API Documentation*.

There is API with documentation. (Dont know if there is better way though :/)

D.

Comment: Thanks will have a look at it 
for now I don't admin have access.

Answer (score 1):

AIUI you need admin to access the most comprehensive web service API, as described by @Dolfa.  You'll need these docs and/or the source if you're developing against their REST API.  The API docs are generated from the source, presumably so they accurately reflect the API in the installed version.

You could:

- [Browse the code on github](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/webservice)
- Clone the version you intend to program against so you can browse the code locally
- Install it and give yourself admin so you can browse the API docs.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of setting up a local Moodle instance, you may be able to figure out a way to run [the php that generates the docs](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/webservice/wsdoc.php).

Once you have a rough idea of an API call, you can often find out the details by looking at responses to command-line requests e.g.

```
curl 'https://your.domain/webservice/rest/server.phpmoodlewsrestformat=json' --data 'wsfunction=core_enrol_get_users_courses&wstoken=[your_ws_token]' --compressed | python -m "json.tool"
```

gives the response

```
{
    "debuginfo": "Missing required key in single structure: userid",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected"
}
```

indicating that the function requires a `userid=[userid]` argument.

Comment: I think you have to have the Developer Messages (/admin/settings.php?section=debugging) set to an elevated level to get that "debuginfo" item. The "Developer" option definitely works.